# Propriedade .length de objeto json retornando numero fora da realidade

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, json

Eu tenho um array json com objetos de duas propriedade, um id e um email, e ele tem somente tres ojetos dentro desse array, mas o numero retornado da propreidade length é 152. Alguém pode me ajuda?

```js
/*JSON*/

[{"id_cli":"1","em_cli":"email@outlook.com"},{"id_cli":"2","em_cli":"email@gmail.com"},{"id_cli":"3","em_cli":"email@gmail.com"}]

/*-------------------------------------------*/

/*Os arquivos PHP creio que não influenciam em nada, mas se precisar eu posto eles aqui*/

function enviarEmails() {

  var titulo = document.getElementById("ti_email").value;
  var email = tinyMCE.get('email').getContent();
  
  if(titulo === "" || email === "") {
   if(titulo === "") {
    alert("Sem Título!");
   } else {
    alert("Sem Conteúdo!");
   }
  } else {
   var formData = new FormData();
   var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
   var emailsClientes;
   var requisicoesDeEnvio = 0;
   var emailsEnviados = 0;
   var aux = 0;
   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(xmlhttp.readyState === 4 && xmlhttp.status === 200) {
     emailsClientes = xmlhttp.responseText;
     console.log(emailsClientes);
     formData = new FormData();
     xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

     formData.append("titulo", titulo);
     formData.append("conteudo", email);
          //Aqui retorna 152 emailsClientes.length
     for(var i = 0; i < emailsClientes.length; i++) {
      $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "enviarEmails.php",
       data: {
        titulo: titulo,
        conteudo: email
       }
      }).done(function(e) {
       if(e == 1) {
        emailsEnviados++;
       }
       console.log(emailsEnviados);
      });
     }
    }
   }
   xmlhttp.open("POST", "getEmailsClientes.php", true);
   xmlhttp.send(formData);
  }
```

```html
<div id="enviarEmails">
 <input type="text" name="ti_email" id="ti_email">
 <textarea name="email" id="email" ></textarea>
 <input type="submit" value="Enviar" onclick="enviarEmails()" />
</div>
```

Comment: emailsClientes.length?

Comment: Sim, estou pegando o tamanho do jeito errado?

Comment: [{"id_cli":"1","em_cli":"email@outlook.com"},{"id_cli":"2","em_cli":"email@gmail.com"},{"id_cli":"3","em_cli":"email@gmail.com"}]

Isso é o que printa quando você dá um console.log(emailsClientes); ?

Comment: amigo, um formData é diferente de um JSON.

Comment: Lucas, sim é isso que printa

Comment: Se o json que você está utilizando está igual ao que você mostrou acima do código o length dele realmente é 3.

Comment: dá um console.log em xmlhttp.responseText.

Comment: Hum, agr que eu vi, eu to mandando um string em formato json devolta pra essa pagnia, deve ser isso que ta retornando, o tamanho da string, alguem sabe uma function que pega um string nesse formato e tranforma em json devolta??

Comment: Faz um teste ... Object.values(emailsClientes).forEach(element => { console.log(element) });

Adiciona essa linha no seu código e veja o que será printado ... (faz isso  antes do for);

Comment: Firebird.. JSON.parse(variavel) ...

Comment: Era Exatamente isso, vlw Lucas. E malz ai kkk, errinho de iniciante esse.

Comment: Acontece... vou colocar a resposta ali embaixo só pra finalizar o tópico.

Answer (score -1):

Passa a variável emails cliente para JSON novamente com o JSON.parse(variavel).

```
JSON.parse(emailsCliente);
```